# UseSelector State is Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

The page does not render, citing `TypeError: state is undefined`, tracing back to this line in **SelectForm.js**: `const filter = useSelector(state => state.filter);`.

I've spent hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried createSelector but that didn't work. I've tried dispatching a "Fetch Initial State" action, and that didn't work. The component is wrapped in provider tags. I'm not sure why I don't have access to the state. At this point I'm unable to see any flaws I've been looking at it for so long.

Code Snippets

**reducer.js**

```
let initialState = {
    filter: {
        country: null,
        state: null,
        level: null,
        team: null
    },

    isDBConnecting: false, 
    isDBConnected: false, 
    isDBError: false 
}

const SelectorReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {        
        case 'DB_CONNECT_INIT':
            return {
                ...state,
                isDBConnecting: true,
                isDBConnected: false,
                isDBError: false,
            };
...
...
}

export default SelectorReducer;
```

**actions.js**

```
export const initializeDBConnection = () => {
    return {
        type: 'DB_CONNECT_INIT'
    }
};
```

**ParentComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'; //import provider to provide component access to the state

//Component imports
import SelectForm from './components/SelectForm'
import SelectorReducer from '.../reducer.js'

const SelectorStore = createStore(SelectorReducer);

const ParentComponent = () => {

    return (
        <div className="page-container">
            <div id="carousel">
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <Provider store={SelectorStore}>
                        <SelectForm />
                    </Provider>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

**SelectForm.js (Child Component, wrapped in Provider tags above)**

```
//IMPORTS
import React from 'react'; //import react
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

//COMPONENT IMPORTS
import FormGroup from '../FormGroup';
import { * as actions } from '.../actions.js';

const SelectForm = (props) => {

    //STATEFUL IMPORTS
    //filter
    const filter = useSelector(state => state.filter);
```

Comment: Does your reducer have a `default` case with `return state;`?

Comment: @NicholasTower oh my god that is maddening. No it did not. THANK YOU!

Comment: You have a syntax error in the path of your reducer inport:  `import SelectorReducer from '.../reducer.js'`.  There should only be 2 periods.  Also, shouldn't `createStore(Reducer)` be `createStore(SelectorReducer)` and shouldn't `<Provider store={TeamSelectorStore}>` be `<Provider store={SelectorStore}>`?

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 I've corrected those syntax errors. They were only present here and not in the code as I did some shortening of the code snippets here to make them more readable. I used '...' to abbreviate the filepath in the import.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Credit to @NicholasTower for the answer in the comments. My reducer did not have a default case in which

```
default: return state
```

Putting that in solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
  let filter = useSelector(state => {
    console.log('State: ', state);
    return state.pieChart.filter;
  });
```

Make sure that you are using the correct object for `state`.

Add a console for debugging and check the `state` object. Many times we use multiple `reducers` which makes our component `state` nested in global object.

Answer (score 1):

We should import useSelector form react-redux and then select user details form store in the following way

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const User = () => {

      const userInfo= useSelector(state => state.user)

      return <div>{userInfo.name}</div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside ParentComponent.js you are saying `<Provider store={TeamSelectorStore}>`. I think you meant to say `<Provider store={SelectorStore}>`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was storing the data coming from Redux state at didMount stage whereas the Redux states weren't fully uploaded yet.

```
  const currentUser = useAuth();
  useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldValue('email', currentUser.email);
  }, []);
```

Adding `currentUser` to `useEffect` dependency array, get it resolved for me:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldValue('email', currentUser.email);
  }, [currentUser]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes having a **break** in the switch block of the reducer can cause the prop not defined in the state.

Answer (score -1):

This error can also happen because of an uppercase / lowercase mistake.

```
let horns = useSelector(state => state.largeRhinohorns);
let horns = useSelector(state => state.largeRhinoHorns);
```