# ReactJS: .useSelector(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I've been following a tutorial for a while and ran into a wall trying to figure this out. Both figuratively and literally.

In a `Dashboard` page, I try to use `useSelector()` to get the state of the `goalSlice` component. This component is very similar to the `authSlice` component, which works just fine (I'll include for comparison to see if it helps get some answers.)

The issue lies within `Dashboard.jsx:13`: "Uncaught TypeError: react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useSelector(...) is undefined"

During runtime, `useSelector()` will return undefined, and I can't figure out why.

I've tried using the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111011/useselector-state-is-undefined), and I've also compared the reducers between `goalSlice` and `authSlice`. Nothing jumps out at me.

I get a hint from eslint, but I'm not understanding what caused it. `goalSlice:73`:*'state' is declared but its value is never read.*

`Dashboard.jsx`

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import GoalForm from '../components/GoalForm'
import Spinner from '../components/Spinner'
import {getGoals, reset} from '../features/goals/goalSlice'

function Dashboard() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const {user} = useSelector((state) => state.auth)
  const { goals, isLoading, isError, message } = useSelector((state) => state.goals)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(isError) {
      console.log(message)
    }
    if(!user) {
      navigate('/login')
    }

    if (user) {
      dispatch(getGoals());
    }

    return () => {
      dispatch(reset());
    }

  }, [user, navigate, isError, message, dispatch])



  return (
    <>
    <section className="heading">
      <h1> Welcome {user.name} </h1>
      <p>Goals Dashboard</p>
    </section>

    <GoalForm/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

`goalSlice.js`

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import goalService from './goalService'

const initialState = {
  goals: [],
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: '',
}

// Create new goal
export const createGoal = createAsyncThunk(
  'goals/create',
  async (goalData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token
      return await goalService.createGoal(goalData, token)
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString()
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    }
  }
)

// Get user goals
export const getGoals = createAsyncThunk(
  'goals/getAll',
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token
      return await goalService.getGoals(token)
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString()
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    }
  }
)

// Delete user goal
export const deleteGoal = createAsyncThunk(
  'goals/delete',
  async (id, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token
      return await goalService.deleteGoal(id, token)
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString()
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    }
  }
)

export const goalSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'goals',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(createGoal.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(createGoal.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.isSuccess = true
        state.goals.push(action.payload)
      })
      .addCase(createGoal.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.isError = true
        state.message = action.payload
      })
      .addCase(getGoals.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(getGoals.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.isSuccess = true
        state.goals = action.payload
      })
      .addCase(getGoals.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.isError = true
        state.message = action.payload
      })
      .addCase(deleteGoal.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(deleteGoal.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.isSuccess = true
        state.goals = state.goals.filter(
          (goal) => goal._id !== action.payload.id
        )
      })
      .addCase(deleteGoal.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.isError = true
        state.message = action.payload
      })
  },
})

export const { reset } = goalSlice.actions
export default goalSlice.reducer
```

`authSlice.js`

```
import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import authService from './authService'
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))

const initialState = {
    user: user ? user : null,
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: ''
}

export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/register', async (user, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        return await authService.register(user)
    } catch (error) {
        const message = (error.response?.data?.message) || error.message || error.toString()
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    }
})

export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/login', async (user, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        return await authService.login(user)
    } catch (error) {
        const message = (error.response?.data?.message) || error.message || error.toString()
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    }
})

export const logoutUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/logout', async () => {
    await authService.logout()
})

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        reset: (state) => {
            state.isError = false
            state.isSuccess = false
            state.isError = false
            state.message = ''
        }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(registerUser.pending, (state) => {
                state.isLoading = true
            })
            .addCase(registerUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.isSuccess = true
                state.user = action.payload
            })
            .addCase(registerUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.isError = true
                state.message = action.payload
                state.user = null
            })
            .addCase(loginUser.pending, (state) => {
                state.isLoading = true
            })
            .addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.isSuccess = true
                state.user = action.payload
            })
            .addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.isError = true
                state.message = action.payload
                state.user = null
            })
            .addCase(logoutUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.user = null
            })
    }
})
export const {reset } = authSlice.actions
export default authSlice.reducer
```

`store.js`

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from '../features/auth/authSlice';
import goalReducer from '../features/goals/goalSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    goal: goalReducer
  },
})
```

Comment: Did you add `goals` slice to the store? Can you show us the `store`'s code?

Comment: I did add the reducer. Edited to include store.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
const { goals, isLoading, isError, message } = useSelector((state) => state.goal)
```

since you have given in your store as `goal`